# rails command reset default path for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working through the tutorial on rail http://ruby.railstutorial.org/
I input the command "Rails" instead of "Rails s", since then testing with Rspec is failing with error:

```
D:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rspec-core-2.11.1\lib\rspec\core\configuration.rb:780:in 'load': cannot load such file --**D:/spec**
```

Although am running my rspec /spec command from app folder itself, it is somehow directing to the wrong path at the root directory instead of the application directory.
Did my "Rails" command reset some configuration related to rpsec path??
Now I have to write the full path to get the test to work

```
D:\rails_projects\sample_app>rsepc /rails_projects\sample_app\spec
```

What has been changed and how can I repair the rsepc path?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running "rsepc spec" in Rails project root directory.

Comment: Am sure. the project directory is
    D:\rails_projects\sample_app and from there am running the command.

Answer (score 0):

I restored the default path of rspec by using the command

```
rspec --default_path (the path)
```

But unfortunately when I turn off Rails serveror I turn off spork server. the default path is getting revered to D: